# restrict user to disable gps option in android

Tags: android, gps

my app will frequently monitors the user location based on GPS..now the riddle was the user can manually disable the GPS option in their device...how to restrict  the user from disabling GPS option.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if GPS is disabled.

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

boolean isGPSEnabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Then fire up a dialog box with intent to open gps settings if isGPSEnabled is false

```
private void showSettingsGPSAlert() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Listen also for changes in your Location listener call backs.

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

         //Do something here. Example tell user that gps is disabled

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I hope these helps, happy coding! :)

Comment: thanks ....is it possible to restrict disabling gps option while the app is running????

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible. So far I cannot find a way to control the settings app of the android system.